# Select Distinct with MAX() using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get all distinct account numbers from 3 tables in SQL Server, but it seems that my way doesn't work, any suggestions?

```
SELECT distinct account, max(date_added) as date_added FROM table_one group by account
union
SELECT distinct account, max(date_added) as date_added, FROM table_two group by account
union
SELECT distinct account, max(date_added) as date_added, FROM table_three group by account  order by account asc
```

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is redundant.  Can you elaborate on what *doesn't work*?

Comment: Explain why you are using max in there.

Comment: The accounts are inserted every month, I need to get the distinct ones from the most current date. The error is a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM', but I don't see any error there.

Comment: you have commas in second and third selects after 'as date_added' just before FROM.

Comment: I saw that now, with the "," commas, now my issue is how to get rid of duplicated account numbers. Thanks for pointing out the commas issue!

Comment: Duplicates occur because of the different dates and tables.  First union all the tables together then get the max date grouping by account.  But as we didn't know if you wanted 1 distinct account record from each table or 1 distinct account and date from all 3 tables. @devart's solution met both methods.

Answer (score 4):

## 1

```
SELECT account, MAX(date_added) AS date_added
FROM table_one
GROUP BY account
UNION
SELECT account, MAX(date_added) AS date_added
FROM table_two
GROUP BY account
UNION
SELECT account, MAX(date_added) AS date_added
FROM table_three
GROUP BY account
ORDER BY account ASC
```

## 2

```
SELECT account, MAX(date_added) AS date_added
FROM (
    SELECT account, date_added
    FROM table_one
    UNION ALL
    SELECT account, date_added
    FROM table_two
    UNION ALL
    SELECT account, date_added
    FROM table_three
) t
GROUP BY account
ORDER BY account ASC
```

Comment: I tested the number 1 here, I am getting duplicated account numbers, thats why I was trying with distinct.

Comment: @Siyual already said that DISTINCT with a GROUP BY is redundant. or you mean something another? please provide for us expected and actual results

Comment: The number 2 option  here got rid of  the duplicated account numbers.

Comment: i don't have a crystal ball. please provide a small example with expected and actual results. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a set of data combining the results then get the max date for each account.  This generates an inline view from which we can get a distinct account and max date added.

```
SELECT account, max(date_Added) as Date_Added from (
SELECT account date_Added FROM table_one 
union
SELECT account, date_added FROM table_two 
union
SELECT account, date_added FROM table_three) B
Group by account
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select account, MAX(date_added) 
FROM (
    SELECT account, date_added FROM table_one 
    union
    SELECT account, date_added FROM table_two
    union
    SELECT account, date_added FROM table_three 
) X
group by account  
order by account asc
```

So what this query does, it unions all the data from all of the three tables in one recordset, so you can work with it as it is one table. Imagine that you have 3 accounts, 1, 2 and 3, and there is following data for them spread accross those 3 tables:

```
Table One
Account | Date Added
--------+-----------
    1   | 01-01-2015
    2   | 01-02-2015

Table Two
Account | Date Added
--------+-----------
    3   | 01-03-2015
    1   | 01-02-2015

Table Three
Account | Date Added
--------+-----------
    2   | 01-04-2015
    3   | 01-05-2015
```

So after union all of those records out of all the three tables we get following 'table' (actually it is recordset stored in memory):

```
Union Data
Account | Date Added
--------+-----------
    1   | 01-01-2015
    2   | 01-02-2015
    3   | 01-03-2015
    1   | 01-02-2015
    2   | 01-04-2015
    3   | 01-05-2015
```

Than we just select account and latest date_added for each of the distinct account found within this set, so we get following results:

```
Result Data
Account | Date Added
--------+-----------
    1   | 01-02-2015
    2   | 01-04-2015
    3   | 01-05-2015
```

Feel free to ask any other questions you get related to this.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: @Odedra, Here you go, sorry for not posting it initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list with all accounts and each account only appears once, then you could do something like:

```
select distinct account from table_one
union
select distinct account from table_two
union 
select distinct account from table_three
```

By using union you will not get duplicate rows, and since you are only selecting account you will get each account only once.

It is however unclear what you are doing with the date_added column.